# react-redux connect do not re-render component, but props getting updated

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a question about react-redux, I am playing with some small test code, to understand how it works.

[Git repository with problematic code](https://github.com/sigvamo/tapp)

Everything looks correct, action generator, reducer, dispatcher, mapStateToProps and connect function.

I will paste code here also:

No State mutation.

But when subcomponent Todo (index.jsx) calls function (onClick event) passed to it from main (problematic component) TodoBox (index.jsx), then 
1. dispatcher gets fired
2. reducer gets fired and returns new State with expected updates
3. mapStateToProps gets fired and returns expected result

But TodoBox component do not re-render
From browser console I can see that this.props of the TodoBox has updated values.

What is going on, I cannot understand, checked many articles and examples but nothing matches.

Who can detect the problem, I need help.

app.js (react entry point)

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import TodoBox from './views/index.jsx';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from './redux_actions.js';

var data = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('initial-data').getAttribute('data-json'));

const todosReducer = function (state={todos: data}, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case actions.UPDATE_TODO:
        let newState = Object.assign({}, state)
        let upd1 = updateRow(newState.todos, 'titel', action.todoUpdate.id, 'checked', action.todoUpdate.checked)
        newState.todos = updateRow(upd1, 'titel', action.todoUpdate.id, 'detail', action.todoUpdate.checked ? 'Done' : 'Sorry not done')
        return newState
      break;
    default:
        return state;
  }
}

function updateRow(tab, where, val, updfield, val2) {
    tab.forEach( (row) => {
        row[where] === val ? row[updfield] = val2 : null
    })
    return tab
}

var Store = createStore(todosReducer)

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={Store}><TodoBox /></Provider>, document.getElementById("app"));
```

index.jsx

```js
import React from 'react';
import * as Redux from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import * as actions from '../redux_actions.js'


class TodoBox extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <div className="todoBox">
                    <h1>Todos</h1>
                    <TodoList data={this.props.todos} func={this.props.handleChange}/>
                    <TodoForm />
                </div>
            );
        }
    }



class TodoList extends React.Component {
  render() {
     let todo = this.props.data.map( (todos) => { return <Todo titel={todos.titel} func={this.props.func} check={todos.checked} key={todos.titel}>{todos.detail}</Todo> } )
     return (
        <div className="todoList">
            <table style={{border: "2px solid black"}}>
              <tbody>
                 {todo}
              </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
     );
  }
}


class Todo extends React.Component {
   render() {
    return (
      <tr>
        <td style={style.tableContent}>
           <input id={this.props.titel} type="checkbox" checked={this.props.checked} onChange={this.props.func}/>
        </td>
        <td style={style.tableContent}>{this.props.titel}</td>
        <td style={style.tableContent}>{this.props.children}</td>
      </tr>
    );
   }
}


Todo.propTypes = {
   titel: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
}


class TodoForm extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div className="todoForm">
        I am a TodoForm.
        </div>
     );
  }
}

let style = {
        tableContent: {
            border: "1px solid black"
        }
    };


const mapStateToProps = function (state) {
   return { todos: state.todos }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = function(dispatch) {
  return {
    handleChange: function(event) {
      dispatch(actions.actionUpdateTodo({id: event.target.id, checked: event.target.checked}));
    }
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TodoBox)
```

redux_actions.jsx

```js
export const UPDATE_TODO = 'UPDATE_TODO'

export function actionUpdateTodo(todoUpdate) {
  return { type: UPDATE_TODO, todoUpdate: todoUpdate }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check http://redux.js.org/docs/Troubleshooting.html

It seems that you are mutating your store. The problem is in your reducer.

I'll strongly suggest you to read about [pure functions](http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/ThreePrinciples.html#changes-are-made-with-pure-functions).

```
const todosReducer = function (state={todos: data}, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case actions.UPDATE_TODO:
        let newState = Object.assign({}, state)
        let upd1 = updateRow(newState.todos, 'titel', action.todoUpdate.id, 'checked', action.todoUpdate.checked)
        newState.todos = {...updateRow(upd1, 'titel', action.todoUpdate.id, 'detail', action.todoUpdate.checked ? 'Done' : 'Sorry not done')} //should do the trick. Although I would strongly suggest you to refactor the updateRow function.
        return newState //even so you are returning a newState, the reference value (todos) is not a new instance.
      break;
    default:
        return state;
  }
}

function updateRow(tab, where, val, updfield, val2) {
    tab.forEach( (row) => {
        row[where] === val ? row[updfield] = val2 : null
    })
    return tab
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I thought that `let newState = Object.assign({}, state)` creates whole new object with all contents. Actually I do not understand why it is mutated. With spread operator it didn't worked but next construction worked `newState.todos = Object.assign([], updateRow(upd1, 'titel', action.todoUpdate.id, 'detail', action.todoUpdate.checked ? 'Done' : 'Sorry not done'))`